# CodeIgniter - how to post value from form as NULL instead of 0

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, codeigniter

In my database it is a table: *tab_companies* and a column *company_phone* (big integer) with defalut value set to NULL.

When somebody fill the form and will leave the *phone number* field empty Code Igniter should add a NULL value to the database, but instead I am having always value '0'.

```
public function add_company()
{
    $data = array(
        'company_short-name'        => $this->input->post('company_short-name'),
        'company_full-name'         => $this->input->post('company_full-name'),
        'company_phone'             => $this->input->post('company_phone'),
        'company_address'           => $this->input->post('company_address'),
    );

    return $this->db->insert('tab_companies', $data);   
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the database row set to NOT NULL?

Comment: Database column 'company_phone' is set to default value NULL.
When somebody add a new company and will leave phone number empty I would like to have a null value in database, not zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could do, set it to `NULL` in case its empty, like:

```
$company_phone = $this->input->post('company_phone');

...
'company_phone'  => (!empty($company_phone)) ? $company_phone : NULL,
...
```

Comment: the *company_short-name* is not a problem becasue it is a text value, however I am having problems with setting NULL to *company_phone*

Comment: @Tikky that was just an example, you could do the same for company_phone

Comment: **@Sudhir:** Thank you - didn't know that I need to set to null even if database is set to Null as a default value.
Your solution works fine for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I just found an automatic solution. You simply should extend `CI_Input` class by overriding the `post()` method.

Create a `MY_Input` class in `/application/core/MY_Input.php`

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {
    public function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL)
    {
        $value= $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);
        return $value === '' ? null : $value;
    }
}
```

From now on, every empty `POST` value will be converted to `NULL`.

Comment: that doesn't work for me when i post an array and one of the key is null, it still inserts 0, driving me mad

Comment: nonetheless it helped me, ty https://stackoverflow.com/a/66394634/10980607

Answer (score 2):

```
//empty to null로
function empty2null($v){
    return empty($v) ? null : $v;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me when i post an array and one of the key is null, it still inserts 0, driving me mad

Answer (score 1):

Based on Sudhir's answer above, I created a small helper function to simplify in my helper file:

```
function nullAllowedInput($name, $post = TRUE)
{
    if($post)
    return (empty($_POST["$name"])) ? NULL : get_instance()->input->post("$name", TRUE);
    return (empty($_GET["$name"])) ? NULL : get_instance()->input->get("$name", TRUE);
}
```

Calling from a controller when necessary:

```
// POST
// load the helper file here or via autoload.php
$data = [
'name' => nullAllowedInput('name'),
'phone' => nullAllowedInput('phone')
];
```

Comment: Pay attention to your empty integer submitted. `empty('')` returns 0 after conversion

Answer (score 0):

This thread gives information: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-72905.html

What I did is to try to fix the data directly in the `post()` function. So I copied the original function, extended it in MY_Input.php and used this function to convert recursively empty strings '' to NULL (in case you submit an array through the form). It works very well and imo should be in codeigniter.

```php
        private function convertEmptyStrToNull($variable_to_fix)
    {
        if (is_array($variable_to_fix))
        {
            foreach ($variable_to_fix as $key => $item)
            {
                $fixed_variable[$key] = $this->convertEmptyStrToNull($item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $fixed_variable = ($variable_to_fix === '') ? NULL : $variable_to_fix; // NOTE: change to a random number to debug, else can't see in log empty ''
        }

        return $fixed_variable;
    }
```

Then in `post()` you pass your values through this instead of returning `return $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);`

```php
        public function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = FALSE)
    {
        // Check if a field has been provided. It's for post() without any argument
        if ($index === NULL AND ! empty($_POST))
        {
            $post = array();

            // Loop through the full _POST array and return it
            foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
            {
                $key_value = $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $key, $xss_clean);

                $post[$key] = $this->convertEmptyStrToNull($key_value);
            }

            return $post;
        }

        // IF A FIELD HAS BEEN PROVIDED (ex: post('name))
        $post_value = $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);

        return $this->convertEmptyStrToNull($post_value);
    }
```

Note: you can of course fix it on each input manually, but since it's the second time I waste time on this, I wanted to find a global solution.