# How to insert a NULL into a database with CodeIgniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, null

I have the same problem, and do not understand the answer #5343141 titled "The proper way to insert a NULL into a database with CodeIgniter". I tried all given answers, without success.

This is my MySQL table:

The 2 last columns:

```
  `id_etablissement_commanditaire` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_etablissement_payeur` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

that makes problem, do have "NULL", so they accept NULL value (tried with phpMyAdmin, it works).

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `id_contact` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `civilite` set('Monsieur','Madame') NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tel_fixe` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `tel_mobile` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `id_etablissement_commanditaire` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_etablissement_payeur` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_contact`),
  KEY `id_etablissement_payeur` (`id_etablissement_payeur`),
  KEY `id_etablissement_commanditaire` (`id_etablissement_commanditaire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;

ALTER TABLE `contacts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_etablissement_payeur`) REFERENCES `etablissements_payeurs` (`id_etablissement_payeur`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_etablissement_commanditaire`) REFERENCES `etablissements_commanditaires` (`id_etablissement_commanditaire`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

This is my CodeIgniter controller code :

1) I need to initialize $_POSTs to '' if they do not exist.

```
if ( ! isset( $_POST['action'] ) )                          $_POST['action'] = '';

if ( ! isset( $_POST['id_contact'] ) )                      $_POST['id_contact'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['service'] ) )                         $_POST['service'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['civilite'] ) )                        $_POST['civilite'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['prenom'] ) )                          $_POST['prenom'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['nom'] ) )                             $_POST['nom'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['email'] ) )                           $_POST['email'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['tel_fixe'] ) )                        $_POST['tel_fixe'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['tel_mobile'] ) )                      $_POST['tel_mobile'] = '';
if ( ! isset( $_POST['fax'] ) )                             $_POST['fax'] = '';

if ( ! isset( $_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire'] ) ) $_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire'] = NULL;
if ( ! isset( $_POST['id_etablissement_payeur'] ) ) $_POST['id_etablissement_payeur'] = NULL;
```

For the last 2 if, I tried to initialize to '' and NULL, but none works.

2) Insert into database :

```
$donnees = array(
'service'=> $_POST['service'],
'civilite'=> $_POST['civilite'],
'prenom'=> $_POST['prenom'],
'nom'=> $_POST['nom'],
'email'=> $_POST['email'],
'tel_fixe'=> $_POST['tel_fixe'],
'tel_mobile'=> $_POST['tel_mobile'],
'fax'=> $_POST['fax'],
'id_etablissement_commanditaire'=> $_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire'] ,
'id_etablissement_payeur'=> $_POST['id_etablissement_payeur']);

$this->db->insert('contacts', $donnees);
```

If I add an empty record CodeIgniter says :

```
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`france-medical-transport`.`contacts`, CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_etablissement_payeur`) REFERENCES `etablissements_payeurs` (`id_etablissement_payeur`) ON DELETE NO ACTION )

INSERT INTO `contacts` (`service`, `civilite`, `prenom`, `nom`, `email`, `tel_fixe`, `tel_mobile`, `fax`, `id_etablissement_commanditaire`, `id_etablissement_payeur`) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
```

Comment: I found a general solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/66394634/10980607

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your DB insert script to not include the columns at all if they have no value:

```
$donnees = array(
'service'=> $_POST['service'],
'civilite'=> $_POST['civilite'],
'prenom'=> $_POST['prenom'],
'nom'=> $_POST['nom'],
'email'=> $_POST['email'],
'tel_fixe'=> $_POST['tel_fixe'],
'tel_mobile'=> $_POST['tel_mobile'],
'fax'=> $_POST['fax']);

if ($this->input->post('id_etablissement_commanditaire')) $donnees['id_etablissement_commanditaire'] = $this->input->post('id_etablissement_commanditaire');

if ($this->input->post('id_etablissement_payeur')) $donnees['id_etablissement_payeur'] = $this->input->post('id_etablissement_payeur');

$this->db->insert('contacts', $donnees);
```

This will allow MySQL to insert the default NULL value without getting confused by any values you're trying to pass in, like an explicit NULL or an empty string.

Comment: Hi Chris, I thought about that, I think I'm going to do it that way, but I would be glad to find a way to use #5343141 answer. That means 3 cases, first : two IDs are set, second : one ID is set but not the other one, third : the opposite of second case.

Comment: This do not like being the good way, as I do not write by myself SQL code as CodeIgniter writes it for me. Does not work at the moment. Looking forward ...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is :

```
$this->db->set('id_etablissement_commanditaire' , $_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire']  , FALSE );
$this->db->set('id_etablissement_payeur'        , $_POST['id_etablissement_payeur']         , FALSE );

$this->db->insert('contacts');
```

This way, the last argument FALSE, means, NULL values won't be escaped, then I have NULL and not 'NULL'.

It works.

**Nota :** FALSE remove '', but it removes `` as well.